# How to make the slider work in a BS collapse element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I am using Bootstrap to create my collapsable elements. I am also using a range selector cdn, and I'm thinking there might be some styles from the BS CSS, specifically to the collapse elements,  that are causing the error in UI.

When I place the range selector outside of the collapse element, it looks and works perfectly.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Slider documentation: https://maxshuty.github.io/accessible-web-components/-->
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#power-range">Power</button>
    </div>
    <div id="power-range" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#container">

    </div>
    <range-selector min-range="0" max-range="15" inputs-for-labels />
  </div>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/maxshuty/accessible-web-components@latest/dist/simpleRange.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I try to put it inside the collapse element, it throws the slider off the page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Slider documentation: https://maxshuty.github.io/accessible-web-components/-->
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#power-range">Power</button>
    </div>
    <div id="power-range" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#container">
      <range-selector min-range="0" max-range="15" inputs-for-labels />
    </div>

  </div>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/maxshuty/accessible-web-components@latest/dist/simpleRange.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't seem to pinpoint where its occuring.

Comment: I posted an answer in reply to your comment.  You only need to make two changes to your existing code.  And the problem isn't really with your code, but rather with the design of the simple range slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will work with 2 minor modifications**

The range slider initializes itself when the page loads and calculates it's size.

When you enclose the slider in a hidden element, like a Bootstrap collapse, it can't calculate the size correctly. And that's why it looks messed up.

There are a couple of ways we could fix this problem. For example, we could call the [slider's reset method](https://github.com/maxshuty/accessible-web-components) to force it to resize correctly. Yet, the simplest solution is to show the collapse on page load, allow the slider to initialize, and then close the collapse. And all this happens without the user noticing anything.

In the markup we add the show invisible class:

```
<div id="power-range" class="collapse show invisible" data-bs-parent="#container">
```

And then in a script tag at the end of the page (or a DOMContentLoaded event handler) we remove show invisible class.

```
<script>
    document.querySelector(".show.invisible").classList.remove("show", "invisible");
</script>
```

**The selected answer**

The selected answer "fixes" the problem by breaking the Bootstrap collapse control. It doesn't work like OP's original code and has some visible UI problems after the page loads.

**Try it**

Run the code snippet to understand how it works.

```js
// hide the collapse after range control has initialized

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector(".show.invisible").classList.remove("show", "invisible");
});
```

```html
<div id="container" class="mb-2 p-2 border">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#power-range">Power</button>
  </div>
  <div id="power-range" class="collapse show invisible" data-bs-parent="#container">
    <range-selector min-range="0" max-range="15" inputs-for-labels />
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/maxshuty/accessible-web-components@latest/dist/simpleRange.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code by defining a custom class, You are using Bootstrap 5.1.0 where 5.1.3 is the latest so I have used it although it works perfectly on both.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    

    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse">
        Link with href
      </a>
    </p>
    <div id="collapse">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <range-selector min-range="0" max-range="1000" />

      </div>
    </div>
 

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/maxshuty/accessible-web-components@latest/dist/simpleRange.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I upvoted, but since I'm new it doesn't count. I really appreciate it, though!

Comment: This answer is totally wrong.

Comment: @Yogi It would be great if you can share with us the correct answer as am also a beginner and a student : )

Comment: @Yogi creating a custom class did fix the slider, but now it loads with the collapsible element opened by default instead of closed. Do you have another solution that works better?